# Check if page parameter is null in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, parameters

```
<c:CPPListViewComponent AccountId="{!IF(ISNULL($CurrentPage.parameters.accId), null,$CurrentPage.parameters.accId)}" RecordTypeValue="CPP"/>
```

I am trying to pass the page parameters as attribute the VF component. In one of the page, the parameter is not need and I need to check if accId is null or not.

When I use the above code it works fine with the parameters. But if the parameter is not passed I get the following error

[image]

Comment: Paste your component code here as well. Nothing seems wrong here and as suggested, check for paramter null state in your component.

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:CPPListViewComponent AccountId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accId}" />
```

does the same thing.

It looks like the error is inside the `c:CPPListViewComponent` component, since it is related to `{!accId}`, there is no `accId` in this code yet.